# Generating random empty boxes in Sudoku squares

Tags: c

I need to come up with a program that generates x% number of squares which are blank in a 9x9 Sudoku square, in which x is determined by the user. The numbers to be printed in the squares are predetermined and fixed in the question.

So I came up with some code to do that, but the problem is that it doesn't work at all. My idea is to create two different arrays, where one is for random row, and another for random column.

Here is my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main ()
{
    int column_random [81], row_random [81], n = 3, k, j, input, number;
    char check = '0';

    printf("Enter percentage of empty squares: ");
    scanf("%d", &input);

    srand ( time ( NULL) );

    number = (input *  81) / 100 ;

    for ( k = 0; k < number; k++ )
    {
        row_random [k] = rand () % 9 ;
        column_random [k] = rand () % 9 ;

        for ( j = 0; j < k; j++ )
        {
            if ( row_random [j] == row_random [k]  &&  column_random [j] == column_random [k] )
            {
                row_random [k] = rand () % 9 ;
                column_random [k] = rand () % 9 ;
                j = 0;
            }
        }
    }


    for ( int i = 0; i < n*n; i++ )
     {
        for ( int j = 0; j < n*n; j++ )
        {
            for ( k = 0; k < number; k++ )
            {
                check = '0';
                if ( j == column_random [k] && i == row_random [k] )
                {
                    check = '1';
                    break;
                }
                else
                {
                    check = '0';
                }
            }

            if ( check == '1' )
            {
                printf("  ");
            }
            else
            {
                printf("%d ",(i*n + i/n + j) % (n*n) + 1);
            }

       }
        printf("\n");   
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Can anyone tell me what's wrong with my code? Or if my idea/concept is wrong?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

- `number = ( input / 100 ) * 81;` will be 0 for `0 <= input < 100` because results of integer division is truncated.
  Try `number = input * 81 / 100;` instead.
- Top row and leftmost column won't become space because extra one is added when generating the random numbers.
  Try using `row_random [k] = rand () % 9;` and `column_random [k] = rand () % 9;`
- Only the last element of `row_random` and `column_random` is effective because `'0'` is assigned to `check` whenever the condition `j == column_random [k] && i == row_random [k]` is false.
  Move `check = '0';` just before the loop `for ( k = 0; k < number; k++ )`.
- *Undefined behavior* will be invoked by using value of uninitialized variable having automatic storage duration `check`, which is indeterminate, when `number = 0`.
  Initialize `check` when declareing it.
- Two characters is printed for non-space (`check == '0'`), but only one character is printed for space (`check == '1'`), so the format will be broken.
  Have it print one more character for space if you want.

These changes will make the behavior better, but number of spaces may be lesser than expected because duplicate position may be selected.
To avoid this, you should

1. List up all 9*9 positions in one array.
2. Shuffle the array.
3. Take the first `number` elements of the shuffled array and use them as the place to turn to space.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I've edited the code with your suggestions. It works most of the time, except for the one fact that it constantly generates a single entry although I enter 100%. I can't figure out what's wrong with my code this time though.

Comment: Oh, the error has been spotted. j needs to be -1 instead of 0. Thanks for all your help!